# how to launch the Stdout of running process

Tags: c#, stdout

I want to display the output of running application ( that i did not started) in my application /
how can I do it?
i tried to do it with the follwing code:

```
rocess[] aProc = Process.GetProcessesByName("processname"); 
 if (aProc.Length > 0)
       _Proc = aProc[0];
        _Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        _Proc.StandardOutput...
```

but i got an exception "StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet."
What the best way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what the error says. You have to start the process to redirect its output.

Comment: ok, so that my question. the process is running already , but i did not dtarted it, so how can i capture the stdout?

Comment: You can't! Perhaps there is some other way using Win32 API.

Comment: thanks, so i will try with Win32 API